# Sending multiple data with SPI interface monitored by an Osciloscope

Tags: spi

I have multiple 32-bit data stored in an array, and I want to sequentially send them by SPI interface. I want to check that my code is correctly sending data by SPI interface, so I upload the code and connect my Linkit7697 to an oscilloscope.
The expecting waveform is like this:
[image]

But it turns out to be like this:
[image]

It seems that all data are composited together in every 32 bits.
What's wrong? Any idea?

Here is my code:

```
#include <SPI.h>

#define SPI_MOSI (11)
#define SPI_MISO (12)
#define SPI_CS (10)
#define SPI_CLK (13)


uint32_t test[]={
  0xF0000000,   //11110000000000000000000000000000 
  0x00F00000,   //00000000111100000000000000000000
  0x0000F000,   //00000000000000001111000000000000
  0x0000000F    //00000000000000000000000000001111
  };            


int i = 0;

void setup() {
  digitalWrite(SPI_CS,HIGH); //Set slave select to high, linkit7697 is Master
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(20000000,MSBFIRST,SPI_MODE0 ));
  
  
}

void loop() {
  
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    digitalWrite(SPI_CS,LOW);
    SPI.transfer(&test[i],4);
    digitalWrite(SPI_CS, HIGH);
    
  }

}
```

Comment: a quick look at the library shows  `transfer16` and `transfer32` functions

Comment: Without fully understanding your problem description, I guess that `SPI.transfer()` actually will cut off everything after the lowest byte of your data element (because it expects one byte), thus only sending one byte per number. As jsotola wrote, the `transfer32()` function is meant for tranferring 32 bit numbers. You should use it

Comment: I've used bitwise operator to transform 32 bits data to two 16 bits data, and using `SPI.transfer16()` to do the transfer. I'm sure that the bitwise operator is working (Because I use serial monitor to print the result). But when I connect the Linkit7697 to the oscilloscope, it shows the waveform as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> SPI.transfer(&test[i],4);
> ```

The `SPI.transfer()` transmit one byte each time and therefore expecting a pointer to a byte (i.e. uint8_t) while you are passing in an address of an `uint32_t`. What you need to do is to cast the address of `uint32_t` into a pointer of `uint8_t` before passing it into the `SPI.transfer`.

```
uint8_t *ptr = (uint8_t *) &test;

SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(20000000,MSBFIRST,SPI_MODE0 ));
digitalWrite(SPI_CS,LOW);
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(test); i++) {
  SPI.transfer(*ptr++, 4);
}
digitalWrite(SPI_CS, HIGH);
SPI.endTransaction();
```

Please also note that Arduino is a little endian machine, so if you have a data as `0x41424344`, the first byte get transmitted will be `0x44`.

One more thing, it is always good to call `SPI.endTransaction()`, it free up the SPI bus to allow other SPI devices to use the data bus.